# How do I assert true if the popup window exists?

Tags: java, selenium, assert, window-handles

Basically I want to be able to assert true if the popup window appears when I click a button which it currently does. How would I go about doing this? Here is my code:

```
 for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}


driver.close();

for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
```

I am switching to that window then closing it and going back to the original. But I would like to be able to assert true if the window pops up.

Comment: you can assert it with the window name anyway you know the window name so in the for loop before clicking the button assert the window title

Comment: So place it here :

printPDF.click();,     

    Assertion,      

    Rest of code.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I usually do:

```
int windowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
printPDF.click();
assertEquals(windowCount + 1, driver.getWindowHandles().size());
// or the Hamcrest way, if you're familiar with it
assertThat(driver.getWindowHandles(), hasSize(windowCount + 1));
// or the FEST way, if you're familiar with it
assertThat(driver.getWindowHandles()).hasSize(windowCount + 1);
```